# What is your preferred way to clean a while loop like this?

Tags: c#, control-flow

I'm a bit OCD about my code and wondered how other people structure the following sample control flow.  I haven't found anything that passes my "pretty" code test.

```
var records = repo.GetRecords(batch:10);

while(records.Any())
{
    var processed = ProcessRecords(records);        
    repo.DeleteRecords(processed);      
    records = repo.GetRecords(batch:10);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: isn't it (deleting elements onne by one) slower than a counter?

Comment: Whats wrong with the way you have it?

Comment: @ChuckConway Nothing more than aesthetics I guess.  Thinking maybe someone had a clever lambda approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @John Kugleman's above, but using while rather than for.

```
while (true)
{
    var records = repo.GetRecords(batch:10);

    if (!records.Any()) break;

    var processed = ProcessRecords(records);        
    repo.DeleteRecords(processed);      
}
```

You can also find questions like this:

[Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

That ask how to "chunkify" a sequence of items.  That technique might or might not apply to your situation.

Assuming a Chunk extension method (similar to @TickleMeElmo's answer or Split from @JaredPar's answer), your code might look like this:

```
foreach (var chunk in repo.GetRecords().Chunk(10))
{
  var processed = ProcessRecords(chunk);
  repo.DeleteRecords(processed);
}
```

This idiom might not work that well if you already have some sort of "chunkification" built into to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true)
{
    var records = repo.GetRecords(batch:10);

    if (!records.Any())
        break;

    var processed = ProcessRecords(records);        
    repo.DeleteRecords(processed);      
}
```

Comment: I normally do it the way you mentioned but I even add a delay before breaking. Would that be a bad idea?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai What do you mean you add a delay before breaking?

Comment: Just a sleep for say 10 seconds to avoid checking again and again if there is nothing to process. I guess this would be an app specific thing.

Comment: This method feels like a kludge. For loops are typically used when you have a known beginning and ending.

Comment: how is this any cleaner, neater or whatever than the original?  I see a `for (;;)` I'll just be wondering wtf?

Comment: @ChuckConway `for (;;)` is the way I write infinite loops. It's equivalent to `while (true)`. The difference is just a matter of style. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.